# Using Jenkins' Conditional BuildStep plugin with Gradle tasks

Tags: gradle

I'd like to select between different Gradle tasks to use when building an Android app on Jenkins.
For example, if an env variable is equal to "Full" the Gradle tasks that will be used are:

```
clean
build
assembleDebug
assembleDebugAndroidTest
```

If the env variable is equal to "Not Full", the Gradle tasks that will be used are:

```
clean
build
```

I know I should used the Conditional BuildStep plugin but the documentation is a bit foggy.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `Strings match` settings from the Conditional Step. Assuming your env variable is named `$YOUR_ENV_VAR` :

For the `Full` case

[image]

For the `Not Full` case

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! This helped